# Deciding what columns to use for partitioning

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I am having trouble deciding what fields of my table to base the partition. Currently there are a total of 8 indexes on the table out of a total of 14 columns. The problem is the indexes are taking up too much space 2 to 1 compared to the data and we need to reduce the size of the DB, and at least maintain current speed. 3 of the indexes have a significantly lower cardinality (in the teens) than the rest (in the millions). There are over 40 million rows in the table.

The index data type looks something like this:

```
datetime
smallint(6) (low cardinality)
varchar(20) (low cardinality)
int(15)
int(15)
varchar(100)
varchar30
char(1) (low cardinality)
```

and a few others. All the indexes are non unique and of type BTREE.

I created a test table and removed the indexes with the lowest cardinality but the queries take a bit longer. I'd like suggestions on two aspects:

- What indexes should be kept and, which should be removed.
- What columns should my partitioning be based on.

The table definition:

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b` int(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ttype` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ag` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `direction` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mode` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `authentication` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `authenticated_id` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `date` (`date`),
  KEY `time` (`time`),
  KEY `b` (`b`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `username` (`username`),
  KEY `source` (`source`),
  KEY `b2` (`b`),
  KEY `status` (`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64678/discussion-on-question-by-wxcoder-deciding-what-columns-to-use-for-partitioning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always have an explicit `PRIMARY KEY` for any InnoDB table.  If practical, use a "natural" key -- a column, or combination of columns, that is unique.  Otherwise, add an `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Learn about "composite indexes" -- this is using more than one column in an index.  It is often a good optimization.  It is *not* the same as having an index on each column.

It is OK for the indexes to take up more space than the data.  A quick survey showed 1/4 of my tables have that.  Having good indexes improves performance far more than the bulkiness hurts performance.

Each Index is updated for each row `INSERTed`, so having too many indexes hurts `INSERTs` (some).

You mentioned partitioning; did you mean "PARTITION BY ..."?  Don't do it unless you have a particular purpose.  I know of only 4 use cases; see [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).

Do not bother to index low-cardinality columns (flags, enums, etc).  They won't be used.  If you have a status flag that is 10/90, then an index on just that column would be used for the 10, but not for the 90.  A composite index *starting* with that column *may* be always useful when all the columns (in the index) are in the `WHERE` clause.

The most important performance setting for InnoDB is to set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to about 70% of *available* RAM.

It is usually a bad idea split `DATE` and `TIME` into two fields.  Look at how messy your `SELECTs` have to be.

How to create good indexes: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Show us some of the `SELECTs`; we can advise further.

Comment: "What indexes should be kept and, which should be removed." _cannot_ be answered without seeing the `SELECTs`.

Comment: Clean up the indexing; then we can discuss `PARTITIONing`.

Comment: Thanks. I discovered that we have a duplicate index on one of the columns and no one knows why so i'm going to test to see if it's necessary and drop it if its' not. The status is a flag that is either 'c' or 'i'. It's roughly 25/75 across the tables. The time has over 800 unique values. I've been doing my own simple queries against the tables but i'll have to wait to see what queries the team is performing against the tables before I can provide you with them.

Comment: You could turn on the slowlog with `long_query_time = 1`.  That would give you some of the queries, particularly the slow ones.  You (a DBA?) can do that without waiting for the engineers.

Comment: Some of the queries rely quite a bit on the status which is a flag that can only be one of two values. What about partitioning the date by range and removing it as an index? The datetime is precise down to the second as it is a monthly table.

Comment: It is OK (and probably good) to have `INDEX(status, foo)`.

Comment: Partitioning, by itself, does _not_ provide any performance benefit.  Replacing an index with partitioning has _no_ benefit.  Replacing one dimension of a 2D "index" with partitioning _could_ have benefit.  Lets see the queries.